# Resize a chart from reactjs

Tags: css

In my application i display a chart.

 **Demo is here** => https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dew-zre6k?file=/src/App.js:51-99
I want to resize the chart with the next values: width:200px and height:200px, but if i do this, my chart becomes like: 
[image]

Above i add: the values for svg tag.
**Question**: how to resize the chart but not loose the aspect of the chart?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the values on your `BarChart` component. The library you are using will then redraw the chart to the size you want (it will make a new SVG with the correct dimensions).

```
    <BarChart
      data={data}
      width={200} // <- change this
      height={200} // <- change this
```

You may need to add some styling to make the axis labels fit, so check the docs of "react-d3-components" for how to do that.

Changing the `width` and `height` directly on the SVG tag won't work. This is because the elements drawn inside the SVG (the bars, axis, etc) are all sized and positioned expecting to be inside a parent of a particular size. This is a pretty deep subject, but if you are interested you can read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/).